# ALOT of symbols appearing on terminal after script run

Tags: command-line, terminal

After the latest Windows 10 update, I've been getting these symbols echoing in the terminal(see pictures). System is also making a beeping sound. I've tried different kinds of terminals and that doesn't really matter.

Scripts also take a lot longer to finish, however they do finish eventually.

Anyone familiar with this behavior?

[image]

Comment: That output looks like binary data, or the content of an executable. I would start by reinstalling your application and see if that solves it.

Comment: reinstalling would take ~8 hours, and I doubt it would fix it, since nothing has been changed on the application itself

Comment: Reinstalling xammp takes 8 hours? Are you kidding me? What kind of special setup do you have for xammp then?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a GUESS, based on the limited information in the question, but I suspect that the console requires some form of interrupting.

I've seen very similar issue using SSH under windows with plink.exe (putty cmd).

Comment: What kind of information would make this question more clear? And what do you mean the console requires interruption?

Comment: Have a look at [Terminals](https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Terminals). For MingGW64 I found going into the Options > Terminal and playing with the terminal type may help you. I make no promises as it been a while since I've had to deal with issues like this. Best of luck to you :)